# FactoryBot creating records + associated with a shared parent

Tags: factory-bot

I have a `user` who owns multiple `trackers`. Each `tracker` belongs_to a polymorphic association called `trackable`, which refers to one of many other classes.

Here are the relationships:

```
# User
has_many :trackers
has_many :dogs
has_many :cats
has_many :horses

# Tracker
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :trackable, polymorphic: true

# Dog, Cat, Horse, etc.
belongs_to :user
has_one :tracker, as: :trackable, dependent: :destroy
```

I would like to create this entire setup in FactoryBot using a tracker factory.

```
factory :tracker do
  user
  traits :dog do
    association :trackable, factory: :dog
  end
  traits :cat do
    association :trackable, factory: :cat
  end
  traits :horse do
    association :trackable, factory: :horse
  end

  after(:build) do |tracker|
    tracker.trackable.user = tracker.user
  end
end
```

The above seems to work only if I set in Tracker: `belongs_to :user, optional: true`. If I make the relationship required, the above code fails.

How can I amend the above code so Tracker can be created together with :dog such that both belong to the same user?

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the most elegant way, but it works.

```
factory :tracker do

  trait :dog do
    user
    association :trackable, factory: :dog
  end
  trait :cat do
    user
    association :trackable, factory: :cat
  end
  trait :horse do
    user
    association :trackable, factory: :horse
  end

  after(:build) do |tracker|
    user = tracker.trackable.user
    tracker.user_id = user.id
  end
end
```

Adding user to the trait immediately creates the associated record (e.g. dog) and its user before the `after(:build)` hook fires. Now that one connection is made, the only thing remaining is to set tracker's user to the dog's user, which is done wit `tracker.user_id = user.id`.